# Read strings of length n as n columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `.txt` file of the following format:

```
10101011
00101010
11001100
00101101
```

How do I read this directly as a dataframe of n (integer) columns? i.e.

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(temp.split())
```

```py
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) with specify number of columns with parameter `widths`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp = """10101011
00101010
11001100
00101101"""

#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' with 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None, widths= [1] * 8)
    
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: fwf is the way to go and using widths makes it perfect. Adding `names = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']` will take care of giving column names

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a simple list comprehension

```
import pandas as pd

text = """10101011
00101010
11001100
00101101"""

df = pd.DataFrame(list(line) for line in text.split('\n'))

print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```